# Bash: Are triple nested loops possible?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename a series of files using a three consistent parts of their names. I decided to test this using `$ echo` beforehand;

```
for i in {No_,Us_,Ca_,G1_,G2_}
do
    for j in {R,L}
    do
        for n in `seq 1 6`
        do
            echo $i$j$n
        done
    done
done
```

This doesn't work. When it's sent to terminal after the second `do` it prints the filenames in the current directory. It also doesn't return any output.

However, a double nested loop works fine;

```
for i in {No_,Us_,Ca_,G1_,G2_}
do
  for j in `seq 1 6`
  do
    echo $i$j
done
done
```

Are triple nested loops impossible in bash? Alternatively, is there a problem with my script?

Comment: It works perfectly on macOS with Bash 3.2. It also works fine on Ubuntu under Bash 4.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> after the second `do` it prints the filenames in the current directory.

Could it be that you indented your script with tabs and copy pasted it into a terminal? Pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> in the terminal starts completion. Often copy pasting tab works as if you pressed tab yourself. In a lot of contexts completion lists the content of the current directory.

Enter your command in one line and try again:

```
for i in {No_,Us_,Ca_,G1_,G2_}; do for j in {R,L}; do for n in `seq 1 6`; do echo $i$j$n; done; done; done
```

By the way, your command could be written as

```
for i in {No_,Us_,Ca_,G1_,G2_}{R,L}{1..6}; do echo "$i"; done
```

or even

```
printf '%s\n' {No,Us,Ca,G1,G2}_{R,L}{1..6}
```

Comment: Yes, the tabs are the problem. Thanks for your help.